# How to set If condition in Where clause in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to display a criteria having multiple conditions, but if any condition is null or not having any value than how to set in where clause. 
Example:

```
where
SR.fk_Designation_ID = @pk_Designation_ID
and SR.fk_SeniorityCategory_ID = @pk_SeniorityCategory_ID
and SR.IsCurrent_Appointment = 1 and SR.fk_SeparationType_ID is null
order by Senority_Joining_For_Order,E.Date_Of_Birth
```

here if `@pk_SeniorityCategory_ID` is `null` than I don't want to include the `and SR.fk_SeniorityCategory_ID = @pk_SeniorityCategory_ID` condition in `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE
SR.fk_Designation_ID = @pk_Designation_ID
AND (@pk_SeniorityCategory_ID IS NULL 
     OR 
     SR.fk_SeniorityCategory_ID = @pk_SeniorityCategory_ID)
AND SR.IsCurrent_Appointment = 1 AND SR.fk_SeparationType_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY Senority_Joining_For_Order,E.Date_Of_Birth
```