# How to apply user filter with if condition in SQL where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I found bunch of similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909442/how-to-set-if-condition-in-where-clause-in-sql) that I have, but couldn't get the exact answer!

I have following condition in SQL where clause

```
declare @status int, @applyUserFilter bit, @user nvarchar(156)

--following are values being set by UI
set @activeStatus = 1
set @applyUserFilter = 1
set @user = 'xyzUser'

--I want to filter the list by users only when @applyUserFilter flag is true otherwise it should return the list for all users

 --This is what i tried but gives syntax error
WHERE ActiveStatus = @activeStatus
      AND CASE WHEN @applyUserFilter = 1 THEN User = @user
```

Note: This shows only where clause code!

Comment: Using `CASE` in a `WHERE` declarative requires you to set a `column` equal to the result of the `CASE`. So when the scenario `@applyUserFilter = 1` is true, a column needs to be set equal to 1 for filtering.

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is: `User = CASE WHEN @applyUserFilter = 1 then @user else null end` with the `else` statement being optional.

Comment: Thanks! @Simon in that case it will not return anything when '@applyUserFilter = 0', in that case i want it to return the full list for all users

Comment: Is this question about MySQL? That doesn't look like MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
    WHERE activeStatus=@activeStatus
    AND (user IN (SELECT user from #users) AND @applyUserFilter=0
    OR user=@user)
```

Comment: This gives me only the list for the user that was passed always!